# Functions needed to be overwritten for own scheduler inheriting cscheduler

Tags: omnet++

I want to create a scheduler inheriting cScheduler. Can someone please tell me which are the functions to be written which must override the functions of cscheduler? Currently, I have written the constructor, destructor, startRun, endRun, guessNextEvent, takeNextEvent, putBackEvent. I have also mentioned  the class in the initialization file and able to successfully build my project but when I run the simulation I get the error: Class TraCIConnection" not found -- perhaps it's code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels with Define_Module()/Define_Channel().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create our own scheduler for Veins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113904/create-our-own-scheduler-for-veins)

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned error has absolutely nothing to do with the custom scheduler you are trying to implement. Omnet complains because you are using the TraCIConnection simple module in the simulation while its C++ code is not linked into the simulation. You may need to add the C++ code to the project or link with an external model that provides that.